# YouTube 'Load More' button using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I just started learning Python and I wanted to know how to deal with the "load more" button on youtube.

For example:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFgquLnL59akiZYuECrz7C6Rm_22-DDBN
This link will only load the first 100 videos in the playlist, and I want to capture all of the videos.

To get the html source code I am using:

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLeI9sYpZVfZVl4B665SV5OzqJ3z4WARDr'
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
```

Goal: I just want to click the Load More button until it no longer exists and then read the html code.

Thanks to anyone who can help w/ this!

Comment: Use Youtube's API. YouTube Data API v3 results are paginated. So you need to get the next page of results for the others. Basically in the response you have [nextPageToken](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#nextPageToken). To get the remaining results, do the same exact call but setting [pageToken](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#pageToken) into that token you received.

Comment: but doesn't the youtube api limit the amount of requests I can make?